# MS access inventory database advice, querying

Tags: ms-access, inventory, querying

I'm building a small inventory database in MS Access (2007), and I have one big dilemma: Should I store purchased (acquired) products/quantities in the same table as sold, with a field for transaction type, or should I separate them in two tables?

I'm working on second option now, but I'm stuck on querying these two tables.

**tblProducts**: ProductID (PK), ProductCode, ProductName
**tblVendorsCustomers**: VndCstID(PK), VndCstName, etc..(Vendors can also be Customers and vice-versa)
**tblPurchase**: PurchaseID(PK), PurchaseNumber(specific), VndCstID(FK), DatePurchased, DueDate
**tblPurchaseDetails**:PDetailsID(PK), PurchaseID(FK), ProductID(FK), QuantityPurchased, PricePurchased
**tblSale**: SaleID(PK), SaleNumber(specific), VndCstID(FK), DateSold, PayDate
**tblSaleDetails**: SDetailsID(PK), SaleID(FK), ProductID(FK), QuantitySold, PriceSold

Two tables (Purchase, Sale) are updating fine. Now, for example, when I want to show a report for a chosen Product, I need to pull data from these two tables, to see purchased quantity (along with Vendor name, date of purchase, and price) and sold quantity (with same set of data) and to calculate available quantity (at a given date). Maybe I'm missing something, but the only way to do this is create two select queries (for each of these tables), than union of these (to pull all transaction data), then a select query of that union, add an identifier field (for row from purchases and row from sales) and criteria for product selection..and I'm stuck on calculating available quantity..I'm guessing sum IIf, but not sure how to use it..

Sorry for such a long post...
Is this the right approach?
Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: please publish you data model here

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply, I have edited my question, providing details.

Comment: In your case I presume that the items purchased will become sold ones sooner or later. So the fields defining the articles are almost the same. (For the sold articles there will be a client and a date, ...). So it would be only natural to store the items in the same table and flag them according to there status. The extra data for sold items can be (and should be) stored in a separate "Order" table. Furthermore, I think that splitting is easier than joining.

Comment: Thanks for a reply..Yep, the fields are practically the same. I'll probably try to store all transactions in the same table, see where it takes me.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: I have already reviewed this on allenbrowne, but I overlooked the Dsum function which is part of the solution. However, that model also uses separate tables for purchased/sold items. Previous comment from y4cine suggests same table with transation type flag/field. That is why I posted this question, I'm looking for an answer/advice sort of pros/cons based on practical application of this kind of database..